# How can i build to a folder that lives one directory down from my current folder

Tags: java, cmd, javac, filepath, shortcut

I want to compile to a file that lives in folder src. The build folder lives in the same folder as my src folder.

So in CMD i am currently in 
C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\src>
I want to build to
C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\build>

I know i can use the "-d" option to specify the path but is there a quick way to say "{1 folder up}\build"?

I would like to do this so i dont have to write out the whole path every time

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file in `C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\src` and you want to reference `C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\build` , you can use `..\build`. Double-period (..) will go up one directory. In fact:

`C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\src\..\build` = `C:\Programming Projects\Java Sample Projects\build`

Try that in windows explorer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `..\build\`, `..` means one folder up.

see also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29